# error while loading shared libraries: libros.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: ssh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS Diamondback on Ubuntu 10.10.

I was running my ROS node without problem until I tried ssh to run a rosnode from a remote machine.

After that, on my own machine, when I run I ROS node which has been working fine earlier using rosrun, I encountered this error message:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libros.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any pointers on how to fix this please? Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12144/error-while-loading-shared-libraries:-libros.so:-cannot-open-shared-object-file:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [Tuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/854/tuan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2011-11-29

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Iqbal](https://answers.ros.org/users/11986/iqbal/) on 2014-02-14**:
Hello Tuan,

I am also having similar kind of problem. Can you please tell me how you resolved that. I am a new user. So, I did not understand the steps you did to fix the problem.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, I did not know exactly what the problem was but I deleted the binary, remake and it worked again. However, I will really appreciate if anyone can share the reason for this happening please?

---

Originally posted by [Tuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/854/tuan/) with karma: 111 on 2011-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0